# JQuery вообще не работает! В чем может быть проблема?

Tags: jquery

jQuery вообще не работает! В чем может быть проблема? Вот весь код выкладываю:

```
<body>
<div id="bg"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script/myscript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

myscript.js:

```
$('#bg').css('background-color','#000');
```

Ставил и так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#bg').css('background-color','green')  ;
});
```

Не работает и не реагирует! В чем дело? У меня уже голова не работает. С утра мучаюсь над ним.

Comment: Ну, вы даёте ))) Подключение библиотеки - должно быть в первую очередь!

Comment: и так не работает все равно

Comment: Вы не могли бы сначала почитать про Яваскрипт каку-нибудь кничечку? А-то у вас десятки абсолютно делитантских вопросов. Ну как можно не знать, что скрипты должны идти по порядку? Ну хоть немного почитайте про язык, ну.

Comment: @navi1893, xто-то я Вас совсем не пойму, чего именно Вы хотите ... Посмотрите, набросал  - http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/hYqDm/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поменяйте местами, так:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/myscript.js"></script>
```

**UPD:**

У Вас что должно получиться? Судя по Вашему коду, блок id="bg" должен окрашиваться в зеленый цвет. Оно так и произойдет, если вы добавите в данный блок какой-либо контент или же просто зададите ему высоту через CSS. Без контента и без явного указания высоты, блок имеет нулевую высоту и как следствие не виден.

Comment: не работает все равно

Comment: Проверьте, верно ли Вы указали путь...

Comment: проверено. Все верно

Comment: Читайте апдейт ответа.

Comment: сработало! Спасибо!

Вопрос еще: Если есть CSS файл и jScript файл, как бы расположение определяет CSS, а размеры - jScript. То они не работают вместе. По крайней мере у меня. Надо в jQuery.CSS сделать все. Так и должно быть?

Comment: Выложите на jsfiddle.net, посмотрим.

Comment: Вообще, должно работать... Надо смотреть Ваш код ...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hYqDm/2/ вот, добавил с описаниями ошибок

Answer (score 2):

Вы загружаете скрипты в не заголовка документа HTML. Потому последовательность имеет значение. Сначала нужно поставить загрузку jQuery и потом выполняемый скрипт.

Comment: не работает опять же

Answer (score 0):

`background-color`  в javascript выглядит как `backgroundСolor`, по аналогии все остальные элементы с дефисом `fname-sname => fnameSname`

Comment: jQuery поддерживает синтаксис из CSS.

Comment: @Алексей Уколов, т.е. ".css('background-color','green')", background-color должен пройти?